# Editing QTableWidget cell with QItemDelegate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm trying to figure out how to reimplement QItemDelegate so that I can draw a QLabel box, and a couple of lines of text in each cell. I've figured out how to do it using QTableWidget().setCellWidget(row, column, QWidget()) but I figure if I redo it so that I'm just drawing shapes and text and plugging it into manually chosen places using setModelData() the code would be more efficient and scalable than if I basically had 300 individual widgets on screen at a time -- especially since I'm not really using most of the functions of said widgets, just how they're painted.

```
class DesignTable(QTableWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    
    self.setRowCount(15)
    self.setColumnCount(6)
    self.horizontalHeader().hide()
    self.verticalHeader().hide()
    for r in range(15):
        for c in range(6):
            self.setCellWidget(r, c, MyTableCell())
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.resizeRowsToContents()

class MyTableCell(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    
    self.layout = QGridLayout()
    self.setStyleSheet('QFrame {border: 3px solid black;}')
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    box = QLabel()
    box.setMinimumSize(50, 50)
    area_1 = QLineEdit()
    area_1.setText('line of text written in code')
    area_2 = QTextEdit()
    self.layout.addWidget(box, 0, 0)
    self.layout.addWidget(area_1, 0, 1)
    self.layout.addWidget(area_2, 1, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
q = QApplication()
w = QMainWindow(None)
d = DesignTable()
w.setCentralWidget(d)
w.show()
sys.exit(q.exec_())
```

is my current code, which nets me the following basic program:

[image: not enough rep, they gave me a link instead]

EDIT_1:
well I literally have next to nothing because I've been trying to figure out the styleditemdelegate for days and I figured, you know I might as well ask here and maybe that'll get me there faster. Basically I'm using the StarDelegate example included and

```
class TestBench(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() == 1:
            if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, painter.brush())
        title = index.data(TitleRole)
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
```

I have understood enough to see that basically if the row is 1, I can use a custom option and if not, it'll just pass it along the regular route. I'm pretty much stuck on what I should change so that I can draw a box and also paint some text onto a table item using delegate. Unless I learn C++ there doesn't seem to be any resources that just lay out simply what kinds of things I can change with a custom delegate.

**TL DR QUESTION**: Can someone help me get some barebones code that would use QItemDelegate with however the modeling data works to paint a square and 2 lines of text into a cell. Or as close as you can, or just point me in the general direction. And meanwhile, I'll keep trying to get it on my end.

Comment: Please show us your attempt in implementing the delegate.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.